# I got a problem runing a django project and got this error DataFrame.drop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, django

```
def forecast(request):
    global graph
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        pass
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
    if request.method == "POST":
        stock_name = request.POST.get('stock_name')
        pred_df, df = calPred(stock_name)
        graph = None
        plot1(df, pred_df, "Stock Price Prediction of "+str(stock_name), 'Date', 'Price', 'blue')
        print(pred_df.reset_index().columns)

        pred_df = pred_df.reset_index()
        pred_df['index'] = pred_df['index'].astype(str)
        json_records = pred_df.to_json(orient='records')
        data = json.loads(json_records)

        df = df.reset_index()
        df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
        df['Open'] = df['Open'].astype(float)
        df = df.iloc[::-1]
        json_records2 = df.head(120).to_json(orient='records')
        data2 = json.loads(json_records2)

        context = {
            'chart': graph,
            'd' : data,
            'd2' : data2,
            'visible': "visible",
        }
        #print('GG :: ',graph)
        return render(request, 'forecast.html', context)
    context = {'visible': "invisible"}
    return render(request, 'forecast.html',context)
```

```
Internal Server Error: /forecast/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ngeti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ngeti\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ngeti\OneDrive\Desktop\c\Stock_price_Prediction-main working\stock\views.py", line 162, in forecast
    pred_df, df = calPred(stock_name)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ngeti\OneDrive\Desktop\c\Stock_price_Prediction-main working\stock\views.py", line 201, in calPred
    x = np.array(df.drop(['Prediction'], 1))
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: DataFrame.drop() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were givenDD
```

Answer (score 0):

definition:

dataframe.drop(labels, axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors)

The axis, index, columns, level, inplace, errors parameters are keyword arguments.

So depending on your needs it should be something like

```
df.drop(['Prediction'], index=1)
```

Comment: if i do that it brings this Cannot specify both 'labels' and 'index'/'columns'. What should i do

Comment: just remove one. I was only giving an example for the keyword arguments vs. positional arguments.